# How to encode labels in multiple pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2

both have 3 columns:

```
c1, c2, c3
```

but in column c3 of df1 I have these unique labels:

```
l1, l2, l3, l4
```

And in column c3 of df2 I have these unique labels:

```
l2, l3, l4, l5
```

I want to encode these labels so last column values of df1 become like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

and df2:

```
2, 3, 4, 5
```

So the encoded labels should have the same name in both dataframes. 
The labels are not in order. And the uncommon labels might be more than 1.

Comment: If that's your exact problem, use `df1['c3'] = df1['c3'].str[1:]`  and `df2['c3'] = df2['c3'].str[1:]`. If you have a more general problem (as I suspect), please change the question to be more general.

Comment: The labels are not in order. And the uncommon labels might be more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use below command :

```
>>> df1
   c3
0  l1
1  l2
2  l3
3  l4
>>> df1["c3"].apply(lambda x: x[-1])
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
```

Apply this to df2 also :

```
>>> df1["c3"].apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```

Comment: It is preferred to avoid using `pandas'` `apply` and `map` if possible, as they create backstage loops. Better option for what you wrote is `df['c3'] = df['c3'].str[-1]`

Comment: I had mentioned apply because the author hasn't mentioned any of the logic for encoding. If it's a specific encoding logic then str will be replaced by some apply function.